# How do you average a group of numbers, after a calculation is done, and a condition is met?

Tags: excel, average

I'm creating a grades spreadsheet for a class and need to find the students average percentage if the grade period is 1 or 2 or 3,etc... However, it must first calculate the percentage (student score/max score).

[image]

I've tried the following code:
=IF(B2:G2=1, AVERAGE(B3:G3/B1:G1))

Pseudocode: For B2 to G2, if grade period is 1, average each "student score" divided by "max score".

In this example: =average((B3/B1),(C3/C1),(D3/D1))

I would like this function as the grade period could change(column E/f/g/etc could be period 1) and I don't want to make lots of custom formulas each grade period. There could be 20 grade periods and each period could have 3-10 grades.

I hope that is clear. Thanks for any help if this is possible!

Comment: I would suggest you to use a helper row (say `Row 4`) to return the result of `Student A Grades/Max Score`, and then use **AVERAGEIF** to find out the average percentage based on grade period. As you did not mention how your row data was generated I cannot comment on how to dynamically look up the range for each row of data.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. All the date in every row is typed in manually. There might be 30 students in a class so that would mean I'd have to make 30 helper rows...

Comment: Do you have the source data which shows `Student Name`, `Grade Period` and `Score` per student per grade period? Do you need the average per student or for the whole class? If you can share an example of your source data there may be a quicker way of finding the average either per student or for whole class per grade period (such as `pivot table`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With helper row, use `AVERAGEIF` function

[image]

## Without helper row, use `Array Formula`.

Write `=AVERAGE(IF($B$2:$G$2=1,$B$3:$G$3/$B$1:$G$1,""))`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
[image]